# How to write a dataframe, graph to pajek format?

Tags: r, export, igraph

I  Would like to save a `igraph graph` or a `dataframe` to `pajek` format.
So I have used the `igraph` package to create `graph object` and then used this `write.graph(graph_activitynetwork,"layer_share","pajek")`  to write the `igraph graph` in `pajek`.but what I am wondering is to create it in customized format :like this :

```
*Vertices 4
1 "Node 1"
2 "Node 2"
3 "Node 3"
4 "Node 4"
*Multiplex
# layer node layer node [weight]
1 1 1 2 2
1 1 2 2 1
1 2 1 1 1
```

now I could just have this format :

```
*Vertices 4
1 "1"
2 "2"
3 "3"
4 "4"
*Edges
# node node weight
1 2 l 
1 3 l 
1 4 l
```

Ps: My own data is in `csv` and `Excel` format.

```
node1 node2 weight layer
```

the graph summary :

```
IGRAPH UNW-  -- 
+ attr:  id (v/c),  weight (e/c), layer1 (e/c),layer2 (e/c)
```

Comment: If the write.graph function isn't providing you with the format you need, you may need to write your own to do the job. Can you please confirm, in the example code above, are you trying to convert the first format to the second? I am not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks for your comment @timothyjgraham. I want to have the first format (Multiplex format) but whatI could do till now is the second format

Comment: The Pajek writer in igraph does not support multiplex networks so you'll have to write the output file in the required format on your own.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?